# How to implement multiple typeahead search input in sveltekit with api request?

Tags: input, server-side, sveltekit, typeahead

I'm trying to implement a feature where every time a user types into an input field, an API request is made, and the results are displayed directly below the input. It's similar to a typeahead or autocomplete functionality. While I could potentially make the request directly from the client and display the results, I need to handle the API request on the server side. This is because all requests must include a token in the header, and the cookie where the token is stored is set to httpOnly:true. Thus, I cannot access this cookie from the client side. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?
Any advice is welcome. Thank you

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Button, Input, Label } from 'flowbite-svelte';

    export let data;
    let taskId = '';

    const onChange = async () => {};
</script>

<div class="max-w-screen-md mx-auto p-6 space-y-8">
    <div class="bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg p-6">
        <div class="text-center mb-8">
            <h2 class="text-2xl bold">Task Form</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="relative">
            <Label class="block mb-1">Task ID</Label>
            <Input
                label="Email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                bind:value={taskId}
                on:change={onChange}
                required
                placeholder="Task id..."
            />

            <br />

            <Label class="block mb-1">유저 닉네임</Label>
            <Input label="nickname" id="nickname" name="nickname" required placeholder="nickname..." />
        </div>
    </div>

    <Button type="submit">Create</Button>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem here?

Comment: I want to send an API request every time a value is entered into an input field, and then display the results from the API directly below the input, similar to a typeahead feature.

Comment: There are already various questions about sending requests, there probably are also questions about displaying data with Svelte. It looks like you have not even tried anything. (Also, any request sent from the client will automatically include all relevant cookies.)

Comment: I've explored typeahead implementations with SvelteKit. In many of the examples I've seen, the common practice was to fetch the entire dataset and then filter it client-side. My goal, however, is to retrieve relevant data in real-time with each input. While this would be straightforward on the client side, as previously mentioned, I need to manage this logic server-side. The reason is that each request must include an accessToken stored in a cookie. The challenge here is that this cookie is set with httpOnly: true, making it inaccessible from the client side.

Comment: You might be right in suggesting that I haven't looked into it deeply enough. Additionally, it's my first time using a framework with server-side support, so there's a learning curve I'm navigating. I'd appreciate any guidance or insights you can offer.

Comment: As noted, the cookie should not matter. Just send a fetch including the search term and return the relevant data, filtered in the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I revisited the Svelte documentation and found the answer to my question. Specifically, I found what I needed at https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing. 
Have a nice day! Thank you!

Comment: Glad you could make it work. Please either answer your question (and accept the answer) or remove the question then.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Statement: I aimed to implement a feature where every time a user inputs into a field, an API request is triggered, and the results are displayed right below the input. It's crucial to note that the API request needs to be handled server-side, not directly from the client. This is due to the necessity to include a token in the request header, which is stored in a cookie set to httpOnly: true. Thus, it's inaccessible from the client side.

Client-side Code:

To avoid making an immediate API request upon every keystroke, I employed a debounce functionality. This ensures the function only gets executed after the user has stopped typing for a specified duration.
I manage the input values for both taskId and nickname using separate state variables.
On each input, the debounce-wrapped API call functions, `_handleTaskInput` and `_handleNicknameInput`, are invoked.
The results are stored in taskResults and nicknameResults and are subsequently displayed to the user.

Server-side Code:

This segment of the code handles the request sent from the client.
It processes the POST request for the /api/task endpoint.
The taskId value is extracted from the request body and based on it, a mock result data is generated and returned.
In a real-world scenario, this section would typically query an external API or database to fetch the actual data.

> Note: When making a fetch call to '/api/task' from the client, it
> corresponds to executing server-side code located at
> /routes/api/task/+server.ts.

Here's my code.

```
// client side
<script lang="ts">
    import debounce from '$lib/utils/debounce';
    import { Button, Input, Label } from 'flowbite-svelte';

    let taskId = '';
    let nickname = '';
    let nicknameResults: any[];
    let taskResults: any[];

    async function _getTaskList() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/task', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ taskId }),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        taskResults = await response.json();
    }

    async function _getNicknameList() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/user', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ nickname }),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        nicknameResults = await response.json();
    }

    function _selectTaskResult(result: { id: number; name: string }) {
        taskId = result.id.toString();
        taskResults = []; // 선택한 후 결과 목록을 숨깁니다.
    }

    function _selectNicknameResult(result: { id: number; name: string }) {
        nickname = result.id.toString();
        nicknameResults = []; // 선택한 후 결과 목록을 숨깁니다.
    }

    const _debouncedTaskList = debounce(_getTaskList, 300);
    const _debouncedNicknameList = debounce(_getNicknameList, 300);

    function _handleTaskInput(event: Event) {
        _debouncedTaskList();
    }

    function _handleNicknameInput(event: Event) {
        _debouncedNicknameList();
    }

    $: console.log({ nickname });
</script>

<div class="max-w-screen-md mx-auto p-6 space-y-8">
    <div class="bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg p-6 min-h-[800px]">
        <div class="text-center mb-8">
            <h2 class="text-2xl bold">Create Task</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="relative">
                <Label class="block mb-1">taskId</Label>
                <Input
                    label="taskId"
                    id="taskId"
                    name="taskId"
                    bind:value={taskId}
                    on:input={_handleTaskInput}
                    required
                    placeholder="task id"
                />
                {#if taskResults && taskResults.length > 0}
                    <div class="absolute w-full top-16 mt-2 bg-white border border-gray-300 z-10">
                        {#each taskResults as taskResult}
                            <div
                                on:keydown={() => _selectTaskResult(taskResult)}
                                on:click={() => _selectTaskResult(taskResult)}
                                class="cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200 p-2"
                            >
                                {taskResult.id}
                            </div>
                        {/each}
                    </div>
                {/if}
            </div>
            <br />

            <div class="relative">
                <Label class="block mb-1">nickname</Label>
                <Input
                    label="nickname"
                    id="nickname"
                    name="nickname"
                    bind:value={nickname}
                    on:input={_handleNicknameInput}
                    required
                    placeholder="nickname"
                />

                {#if nicknameResults && nicknameResults.length > 0}
                    <div class="absolute w-full top-16 mt-2 bg-white border border-gray-300 z-10">
                        {#each nicknameResults as nicknameResult}
                            <div
                                on:keydown={() => _selectNicknameResult(nicknameResult)}
                                on:click={() => _selectNicknameResult(nicknameResult)}
                                class="cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200 p-2"
                            >
                                {nicknameResult.id}
                            </div>
                        {/each}
                    </div>
                {/if}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <Button type="submit">Create</Button>
</div>
```

```
// server side 
// path : /routes/task/+server.ts

import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types';

export const POST: RequestHandler = async ({ request }) => {
    const { taskId } = await request.json();

    if (!taskId) return json([]);

    // Api call here

    console.log({ taskId });
    const result = [
        { id: 1, name: taskId },
        { id: 2, name: taskId },
        { id: 3, name: taskId },
        { id: 4, name: taskId },
        { id: 5, name: taskId },
        { id: 6, name: taskId }
    ];
    return json(result);
};
```